# Term for "a solution that's just barely good enough to stifle better solutions"?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, psychology

There's an expression that, "Perfect is the enemy of good". What is **the opposite of that expression**? I'm talking about times when "marginally adequate" is also "the enemy of good". Is there a more concise and evocative way to say that? "Golden handcuffs" might be in the right ballpark, if they were downgraded to "Bronze handcuffs".

For example: A product that suits most people's needs most of the time, but is unsuitable for most people some of the time, and some people most of the time. Yet, for whatever reason, this product is **completely dominant**, and can't be dislodged from its market position. Some possible reasons include:

- It looks more polished than alternatives (but it's a ["Gilded Cage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority) or ["Walled Garden"](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/walled-garden))
- It's easier to learn the basics
- It had [first-mover advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-mover_advantage) in the market
- "Tyranny of the majority". Here are some highlights from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyranny_of_the_majority):

> ...an inherent weakness to majority rule in which the majority of an
> electorate pursues exclusively its own objectives at the expense of
> those of the minority factions.
>
> ...a decision "which bases its claim to rule upon numbers, not upon
> rightness or excellence".

To give a more specific example of a product: I'm talking about the kind of criticism you saw against "Wintel" (Windows and Intel) at one time.

Arguably, platforms that make money by selling your data or showing you ads (Facebook, Google, etc.) are also examples of this. They may be very effective, but their core business model is extremely objectionable to some people.

Another example is hypertext, which has some major failings like "link rot", links that only go in one direction, no inherent licensing mechanism, etc. Attempts to fix hypertext have been kludge on top of kludge. I once heard hypertext described as, "The worst thing that could possibly work."

In the same vein, email has some problems like "spam" that have been so intractable that there's an [oft-cited joke](https://craphound.com/spamsolutions.txt) about "Why your solution to spam won't work".

Comment: What about something like - The existing product’s market position is **precarious**?

Comment: It's not quite right but I am reminded of "Better the Devil you know" to describe a situation you would prefer to a one that is yet unknown.

Comment: @k1eran In this situation, the existing product's market position is *too stable*. That's why it's stifling better solutions.

Comment: "The good is the enemy of the best."

Comment: I would call this product **ingrained**, which has the connotation of being "comfortable but not great"

Comment: I can't answer but I don't understand why someone wasted a downvote on a novel question. I have compensated for it.

Comment: The term that comes to my mind is "good enough"

Comment: [Harry Clements explained how Cessna came to design their "optimised mediocrity":](https://www.euroga.org/forums/taildragger-v-tricycle-landing-gear/1101?page=2). This phase is understood in different ways by different people, but the Cessna 172 is the best-selling airplane of all time - by miles.

Comment: What about then saying: *The product is simply **good enough**.*

Comment: @k1eran No, "usually adequate, but occasionally worthless" is not the same as "good enough". That's exactly my point, and it's a tough distinction to make - which is why I'm looking for a better term for this phenomenon!

Comment: “Dominant for whatever reason” isn’t a very good explanation. Are there niche markets unmet? Most products have a wide range of quality and price, moreso in the U S than elsewhere (I think)—true of housings, transportation, clothings (suits to socks), food. Only with government-blessed monopolies is there likely to be only one choice, and even there options exist. A network-effects concentration may result in use of a single word processor, but breaks down in actual publishing.

Comment: Not quite the same thing but "[nobody gets fired for buying IBM](https://www.forbes.com/sites/duenablomstrom1/2018/11/30/nobody-gets-fired-for-buying-ibm-but-they-should/?sh=4bca2d6548fc)" describes the case where purchasing something that's good enough, but not necessarily optimal, guarantees job security. It relates to the idea of a company's product having a dominant market share (as IBM once did) because it mostly works well enough that it won't be a disaster if you buy it, regardless of whether there are better alternatives from smaller competitors.

Comment: I would suggest "**Perfect imperfection**" but that seems already to have been covered in a film, book, song, and as a philosophical concept: I therefore suggest "**Imperfect perfection**"

Comment: Reminds me of the "90% solution", which handles all of the necessary cases but none of the hard cases.  There isn't an obvious definitive source, but this post expresses it well enough: https://geekboss.com/the-90-percent-solution/

Comment: @Lambie Please define "a widget with an edge" - this phrasing intrigues me, and it's not googleable (Microsoft Edge dominates the search results)

Answer (score 2):

It is a **satisficing** solution (or product per your examples). *Satisfice* (and *satisficing*) is a portmanteau word combined from *satisfy* and *suffice*; and coined by Herbert Simon (an American political scientist) in 1956. This term describes a solution/choice/outcome that is satisfying and sufficient; and it is often used in the context of decision-making in business, psychology, economics and marketing. Here are more details and relevant excerpts from two sources (one in business, one in psychology):

> Satisficing is a decision-making strategy that aims for a satisfactory or adequate result, rather than the optimal solution. The satisficing strategy can include adopting a minimalist approach in regards to achieving the first attainable resolution that meets basic acceptable outcomes.
>
> - Customers often select a product that is good enough, rather than perfect, and that's an example of satisficing.
> - A limitation of satisficing is that there is no strict definition of an adequate or acceptable outcome.
>
> <sub>*[investopedia.com](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/satisficing.asp)*</sub>

> "Satisficing" can also be regarded as combining "satisfying" and "sacrificing." In this usage the satisficing solution satisfies some criteria and sacrifices others.
>
> ... from a decision theory point of view, the distinction between "optimizing" and "satisficing" is essentially a stylistic issue (that can nevertheless be very important in certain applications) rather than a substantive issue. What is important to determine is what should be optimized and what should be satisficed.
>
> <sub>[*psychology.fandom.com*](https://psychology.fandom.com/wiki/Satisficing)</sub>

The decision-making process that involves satisficing is explained with *bounded rationality* also:

> Bounded rationality is a human decision-making process in which we attempt to satisfice, rather than optimize. In other words, we seek a decision that will be good enough, rather than the best possible decision. - *[thedecisionlab.com](https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/bounded-rationality)*

Note: There is an earlier obsolete verb *satisfice* which is an alteration of *satisfy*. *OED* mentions that it is still used in this sense in northern dialects of England; and adds that it is either after its etymon classical Latin *satisfacere* or after verbs in *-fice*, e.g. suffice *v.*

Comment: This is on the right track, but people who use *satisficing* normally don't intend to imply by this term any kind of a negative judgment of that mode of practical reasoning. The OP seems to want a term for something like satisficing that would imply a negative judgment of it. Also, the OP is looking for a term for something **barely** good, while satisficing typically leads to results that are better than that.

Comment: @jsw29 Negative judgement, though it doesn't have to be involved in all the examples, is part of the decision-making process and more within _bounded rationality_ theory; however _satisficing_ can involve too, as a strategy. I've found this excerpt in the _Bounded Rationality_ article in Wikipedia: "Three major topics covered by the works of Daniel Kahneman and Amos Tversky include Heuristics of judgement, risky choice, and framing effect, which were a culmination of research that fit under what was defined by Herbert A. Simon as the Psychology of Bounded Rationality."

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the word tokenistic, which means to make only a token effort or doing no more than the minimum.

Maybe something along the lines of 'tokenistic solutions that do nothing but stifle innovation'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).